# Property with Type parameter?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, types, properties

It is possible in **VB.Net** to design a readonly property which accepts a type paramater like this pseudo-example?:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Resources(of T) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Get ' Returns the value of a function.
        Return Me.GetResources(Of T)()
    End Get
End Property
```

And also an overload like this?:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Resources As IEnumerable(Of Object)
    Get ' Returns the value of a function.
        Return Me.GetResources(Of Object)()
    End Get
End Property
```

PS: The definition of my Class is not generic.

Comment: If the class is not generic then where would T come from?

Comment: @Plutonix: A method can be generic at the method level (T comes from the method definition: e.g., "Sub Test(Of T)(p As T)").  Unfortunately, you can't do this with properties.

Comment: It's a restriction in both VB and C# (or even C++/CLI) - you simply cannot have generic properties.  It would come in handy for cases such as your example, but someone with more experience with the inner workings of the CLR might offer some insight into this restriction.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas [generic properties on a generic class](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JlhvXw) are legal.  The problem here is a) the class is not generic so the first Prop contains two-thirds of the answer: a `function(of T) As T` - implement it as a method and the related lazy load aspect is also handled. b) Code block 2 is not a proper overload since *only* the return type differs.  Overloads are defined by param types, number and order, not return type.  What you *cannot* have is a Prop which decides for itself what type to return (T) which is what the OP *seems* to be after and why I asked.

Comment: @Plutonix: I guess we're just disagreeing on terminology - when I say "generic method" I just mean a method which introduces a generic parameter 'T' instead of the class introducing 'T'.  You cannot have a property which introduces a generic parameter.  The OP's first example is illegal in all .NET languages for this reason since it's a property which attempts to introduce a generic parameter.

Comment: I was reading all your explanations guys, feel free to expose an answer to mark it as the accepted one, and thanks both for explaining that there is any viable alternative than designing a generic class, but that will alter the behavior which I don't want. so, this problem is solved (in a unfavorable way)

Comment: `What you cannot have is a Prop which decides for itself what type to return (T) which is what the OP seems to be after and why I asked.` yes that is exactlly what I pretended to do.

Answer (score 1):

Frustratingly, .Net doesn't allow it. It gives the error we find here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc32065

Accessed 10/2017:

#### Type parameters cannot be specified on this declaration

A programming element is declared with a type parameter list, but the programming element is not eligible to be a generic type.

Programming elements that are not eligible to be generic include properties, operators, events, and constructors. Declaring any of these elements with a type parameter list results in this error.

Error ID: BC32065

To correct this error

- Remove the Of keyword and the type parameters from the declaration.